# Pandas - Extract data from Dataframe in a specified format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that has data pulled from another system in the below format:

```
id,value
1001,--- !ruby/hash:Action::Params
         values:
         - 'ABC'
1002,--- !ruby/hash: Action:: Params
         values:
         - 'DEF'
         - '123'
         - 'Hello'
```

I am trying to have the data extracted from the above Dataframe and get the below format:

```
id, value
1001,ABC
1002,DEF
1002,123
1002,Hello
```

Output of df.head().to_dict()

```
{0: {0: 1001, 1: 1002, 2: 1003, 3: 1004, 4: 1005},
 1: {0: '--- !ruby/hash:Action::Params
     values:
     - 'ABC', 
     1: '!ruby/hash: Action:: Params
     values:
     - 'DEF'
     - '123'
     - 'Hello',
     2: '!ruby/hash: Action:: Params
     values:
     - '456'
     - '6666'
     - 'Bye'
     3: '!ruby/hash: Action:: Params
     values:
     - 'ffff'
     - 'tte',
     4: '!ruby/hash: Action:: Params
     values:
     - 'njytg'
}}
```

Comment: is it always three letters you're extracting?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity No. It could vary. My bad the sample I shared had 3 characters..

Comment: Do you mind to share `df.head().to_dict()` for your original data?

Comment: @rpanai, I have edited my initial post with the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: Did you add returns to your `to_dict` output? This looks weird.

Comment: It is. I cant load it. What about `print(df.head())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `Series.str.extractall` with `regular expression`.

In this case we use `positive lookbehind` and `positive lookahead`:

- `(?<=\')`: Characters preceded by a quotation mark `'`
- `(?=\')`: Characters followed by a quotation mark `'`

```
values = df['value'].str.extractall("(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')").replace('-',np.NaN, regex=True).dropna()
df = values.droplevel(1).join(df['id']).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0:'values'})

  values    id
0  ABC    1001
1  DEF    1002
2  123    1002
3  Hello  1002
```

Input example data used:

```
     id                                                          value
0  1001  !ruby/hash:Action::Params values: - 'ABC'                    
1  1002  !ruby/hash: Action:: Params values: - 'DEF' - '123' - 'Hello'
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I see droplevel was introduced from pandas 0.24.0.. Is there an alternative method of doing this using old versions of pandas. Sorry if I asking a lot from you on this. Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `print(pd.__version__)`?

Comment: It is `0.23.0` .. I figured by just applying reset_index() I was able to get the desired output. Thanks again